# Interlinking GUI in some other language and Python

Tags: python

I have done coding for mathematical simulation of Theory of Computation concepts in Python such as grammar checking and other stuff. My Problem is that I have to build a decent looking GUI for it .

I have looked at PyQt4 and the lack of documentation is really a big deterrent. I have looked at other graphical libraries in Python and they are not helping me so is there a way that I can write the GUI stuff in some other language and integrate python in it.

The problem is that I want mathematical stuff like circles, epsilon on runtime which have drag and drop events available on them. So simply creating an image is not an option.

I am sorry for being a little non specific here but the problem is that I am looking for things that can help here. I have asked a question before too for GUI and unfortunately I could'nt find the right answers for it.

Is there a way I can get around this problem.

Thanks a lot....

Comment: PyQt and lack of documentation? Qt documentation is huge and detailed, PyQt's is mostly taken straight from there (so large parts are C++ - but that never stopped me, and I'm certainly not a C++ guy).

Comment: By lack of documentation I meant lack of examples. I had the book Rapid GUI with PyQt and even that does not help in explaining how to use QGraphicItems in an example.

Comment: Well, that's propably because drawing manually is a huge PITA, black magic and very rarely needed. Depending on what you're drawing, matplotlib might help.

Comment: @delnan :- But I thought matplotlib does not have drag and drop for individual widgets. Am I wrong??

Comment: Not a criticism of looking for examples when you're probably working on an academic project, but during my professional accomplishments I've found that working without any example is an extremely valuable skill and if you're working in teams on projects where you need an example to proceed, you'll get the least interesting and least important assignments. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look again at PyQT4 if you want something *decent looking*.  PyQt has an an example directory in the source code. KDE uses QT and they have a lot examples too. You have to understand that it is a binding against QT4. When I use it with python I usually just have the QT docs open. Its pretty easy to translate.

You could look at PyGTK also, but again, it is a binding against GTK.

Answer (score 0):

Most python guis I recommend tkinter but drag 'n drop isn't built into tkinter yet and I'm not a huge fan of the other libraries.

Have you thought about IronPython in .Net and WPF? You'll need to learn the xaml syntax but it's not much harder than html (technically, it's stricter and simpler but you need to learn some library controls it will instantiate). There are free versions of visual studio for all of this.

Another simple way would be to expose a command line or webservice interface to your python routines.

Comment: Drag and drop may not be built in, but simple drag and drop is _really_ easy to implement within an app, especially in the canvas, but also between other widgets in the same app.